# How to print header and footer on every printed page of a document?

Tags: html

Is it possible to print HTML pages with custom headers and footers on each printed page?

I'd like to add the word "UNCLASSIFIED" in Red, Arial, size 16pt to the top and bottom of every printed page, regardless of the content.

To clarify, if the document was printed onto 5 pages, each page should have the custom header and footer.

Does anybody know if this is possible using HTML/CSS?

```css
      .empty-header {
        height: 0px
      }

      .empty-footer {
        height: 0px
      }

      @media print {
        .empty-header {
          height: 100px
        }

        .empty-footer {
          height: 20px
        }
      }

      header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
      }

      footer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
      }

      @media print {

        header,
        footer {
          position: fixed;
          color: #777;
        }

        footer {
          bottom: 0;
        }
      }
```

```html
<header>
      <h3>Header Example</h3>
      <li>This is an example of a header.</li>
    </header>
    <table class=paging>
      <thead class="empty-header"></thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <ol>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
              <li>This is the main content of the page.</li>
            </ol>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot class="empty-footer"></tfoot>
    </table>
    <footer>(repeated footer)</footer>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [web standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/) which has been proposed for managing paged media has unfortunately not been fully implemented yet by the major browsers.

In the meantime, suggest you use the excellent Javascript library [Paged.js](https://pagedjs.org) to accomplish this. It works as a polyfill, allowing you to use the web standard to specify your headers and footers, and then interpreting that in a way that current browsers can understand. The way I am using it here in this snippet will display the paginated results both on screen and when printed, but if you need it to display paginated results in print view only, that is possible.

```css
@page {
  size: A4;
  @top-center {
    content: "UNCLASSIFIED";
    color: red;
  }
  @bottom-center {
    content: "UNCLASSIFIED";
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pagedjs/dist/paged.polyfill.js"></script>
<h1>This is the title of the document</h1>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<p>This is the main content of the document.</p>
<h4><br>** This is the end of the document. **</h4>
```